# Import existing BlackBerry project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

How can I import existing Blackberry projects into eclipse?

I found this development guide for BlackBerry Eclipse users, but I didn't find any **.jdw** file:
[Import a BlackBerry application project from an existing workspace](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23674/Import_BB_app_from_BBJDE_workspace_655907_11.jsp)

When I make new project and copy all the folder src and res I obtain an error that there is a file  missing and there is no specification of type of the name of this file
`Error: Cannot run program "jar": CreateProcess error=2`.

Can any one help me to run this project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click File-->New-->Blackberry Project-->Create project form existing resource --> then browse to your project folder and click finish.

Answer (score 0):

Use this BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse guide: [Add a .jar file dependency](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23674/Add_jar_dependency_923677_11.jsp)